# section formatting, font size

Tags: sectioning

I have created a template for assigning tasks

Can this be made better in terms of symmetry

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
                \begin{center}{\large \textbf{HANDING / TAKING OVER}}\end{center}
            \begin{description}         

\item {\textbf {\fbox{AON for CHT}}}
\item 11 Nov 2019
\subitem \fcolorbox{black}{green}{Preetha} check progress with IFA
\item 12 Nov 2019
\subitem \fcolorbox{black}{green}{Preetha} to liaise with IFA
            \end{description}
            \begin{description}         
\item {\textbf {\fbox{AON for DEO}}}
\item 11 Nov 2019
            % \begin{enumerate}[labelindent=\parindent,leftmargin=*, label=\alph*)]
\subitem \fcolorbox{black}{green}{Preetha} check progress with IFA
\item 12 Nov 2019
\subitem \fcolorbox{black}{green}{Preetha} to liaise with IFA
            % \end{enumerate}
            \end{description}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: why doesn't my image show?

Comment: the image markup is in your verbatim code block

Comment: It gives no errors but `\subitem` isn't really intended for general lists it is defined in article class specifically as part of the index code

Comment: any suggestions for a better layout--a better template--alternatives to descriptive list--anything for improvement--dates are repetitive--how to ??